# Video lan problem with v. 14.04

Tags: networking, apt

I keep getting this error message upon every `sudo apt-get update` command, and plenty f other times while downloading and installing new software and packages... I was wondering if someone could help.

```
E: GPG error: http://donwload.vidoelan.org  InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
```

Answer (score 0):

That URL you have there is bad (perhaps even malicious ?) - note that you have

```
http://donwload.vidoelan.org/
         ^^        ^^
```

Which is incorrect - it should be https://download.videolan.org/, which *does* work, whereas the one you have just gives an empty page.

You need to remove this repository. To do so, open the "Software sources" utility (find it in the dash), go to the "Other software tab", and, if there's an entry for Videolan (or Vidoelan..), uncheck it.

Comment: Thanks Jonas that made me feel like a bonehead. I didn't even notice. And yes it must have been malicious, because now I'm getting other error messages from sudo apt-get update.

Comment: @Digizombie - What are the other error messages ? I don't think it's malicious, as going to that website in the browser just gives an empty page. Probably just some bad settings somewhere.

Comment: I now get these errors very frequently Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/locales_2.22-9_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)                                                                                                                                                 and                                                                                                                                                      E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: @Digizombie, try doing `sudo apt-get -f install`, as it says/

Comment: This is error feed back I go from doing that -    thedpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/locales_2.22-9_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/sbin/update-locale', which is also in package libc-bin 2.19-0ubuntu6.9

Comment: dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Try deleting the file  `/var/cache/apt/archives/locales_2.22-9_all.deb `.